# How to check complete response time for a http request on glassfish?

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Problem : Service A (runs on spring+tomcat) makes a http call to Service B (runs on EE+glassfish).

Service A log says : http call took : ~10 seconds (this happens infrequently, normal response time is ~20 ms).

Service B log says (for the same request): it took 25 ms.

ELB of Service B says : backend_processing_time = 10 seconds.

I need to figure out exactly where that time was spent.

The response time logging on Service B is configured within a @WebFilter that implements Filter.

Is the time spent in glassfish? queue? on the network?

This is production setup. What more logging can I add/enable to figure this out?
Any help is appreciated.